# How to use AMD GPU on Mac?

Tags: gpu, osx

Just wondering if anything has been adjusted to allow for AMD on Mac with GPU.

For instance a test scene rendered with and GPU on windows got 1min30 render time on the Mac with same and GPU its at 7min or so.

Any way to utilize the and gpu fully?  The Prorender from AMD sounds nice but only works on windows?  Just bringing this up if Blender can think of something.

Comment: Questions about hardware are off-topic here. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic.

Comment: im referring to the rendering in blender??  the answer: there is a way to use a backend with AMD to trick it as meta in blenderl.  improved render time to 2min.  still not as fast as on windows though at 1:30.